# Implementing function overloading

Tags: javascript, typescript

Since javascript does not support function overloading typescript does not support it. However this is a valid interface declaration:

```
// function overloading only in the interface 
interface IFoo{
    test(x:string);
    test(x:number);
}

var x:IFoo;
x.test(1);
x.test("asdf");
```

But how can I implement this interface. Typescript does not allow this code:

```
// function overloading only in the interface 
interface IFoo{
    test(x:string);
    test(x:number);
}

class foo implements IFoo{
    test(x:string){

    }
    test(x:number){

    }
}
```

[Try it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=//%20function%20overloading%20only%20in%20the%20interface%20%0Ainterface%20IFoo%7B%0A%09test%28x%3astring%29;%0A%09test%28x%3anumber%29;%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20foo%20implements%20IFoo%7B%0A%09test%28x%3astring%29%7B%0A%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%09test%28x%3anumber%29%7B%0A%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: You have found a bug in the translator I'd say.

Comment: The reason for adding the functionality to interfaces is quite clear. This is what allows us to describe (via interfaces) how jquery works. But how I would write something like jquery in typescript is what I am trying to understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212625/typescript-function-overloading)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function overloading in Typescript is done like this:

```
class foo implements IFoo {
    test(x: string);
    test(x: number);
    test(x: any) {
        if (typeof x === "string") {
            //string code
        } else {
            //number code
        }
    }
}
```