# TypeScript invalid overload signatures - incompatible with implementation

Tags: javascript, typescript

I keep getting following error:

```
error TS2394: Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation.
```

for following code:

```
import Registry = require('../class/Registry');

type Format = Function;

type FormatRegistry = {
  [s: string]: Format;
}

var registry = new Registry<Format>();

function formatAPI(): FormatRegistry; // get all formats // HERE GOES THE COMPILER ERROR
function formatAPI(name: string): Format; // get format
function formatAPI(name: string, format: Format): void; // register format
function formatAPI(formatMap: FormatRegistry): void; // register many formats
function formatAPI(nameOrMap?: string|FormatRegistry, callback?: Format): FormatRegistry|Format|void {
  if (typeof nameOrMap === 'object') {
    registry.registerMany(nameOrMap);
  } else if (typeof nameOrMap === 'string') {
    if (callback) {
      registry.register(nameOrMap, callback);
    } else {
      return registry.get(nameOrMap);
    }
  } else {
    return registry.list();
  } 
}

export = formatAPI;
```

**I can't see what is wrong in the function type overloading above**. I tried to remove functions signatures (and according types) piece by piece but I failed - I achieved an empty function.

The logic behind the codeis fine (all tests pass), just the overloads are somehow invalid.

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651860/proper-way-to-override-function-with-different-param-types-in-typescript).

Comment: @CoreyAlix so how should I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This all works without errors for me in the typescript playground:

```
class Registry<T> {
    registerMany(items: FormatRegistry) { } 
    register(name: string, cb: Format) { }
    get(name: string) { }
    list() { }
}

type Format = Function;

type FormatRegistry = {
  [s: string]: Format;
}

var registry = new Registry<Format>();

function formatAPI(): FormatRegistry; // get all formats // HERE GOES THE COMPILER ERROR
function formatAPI(name: string): Format; // get format
function formatAPI(name: string, format: Format): void; // register format
function formatAPI(formatMap: FormatRegistry): void; // register many formats
function formatAPI(nameOrMap?: string|FormatRegistry, callback?: Format): FormatRegistry|Format|void {
  if (typeof nameOrMap === 'object') {
    registry.registerMany(nameOrMap);
  } else if (typeof nameOrMap === 'string') {
    if (callback) {
      registry.register(nameOrMap, callback);
    } else {
      return registry.get(nameOrMap);
    }
  } else {
    return registry.list();
  } 
}

export = formatAPI;
```

Comment: My code works for me in typescript playground as well. But the compiler on my computer throws this error...

Comment: What version of tsc?

Comment: typescript "1.8.9"

Comment: I updated to 1.8.10 and no problems.  Share your tsconfig.json maybe.  I created a registry.ts and it still worked:

`export type Format = Function;

export type FormatRegistry = {
  [s: string]: Format;
}

export class Registry<T> {
    registerMany(items: FormatRegistry) { } 
    register(name: string, cb: Format) { }
    get(name: string) { }
    list() { }
}`