# Method overriding in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have two components, one is parent and the other is child. Child extends from Parent. Parent has a method open(). Child overloads open() by rewriting and adding a parameter. It results in an error: open() is a property, and the property types do not match across classes.

```
open() => void
```

is not equal to

```
open(message: string) => void
```

Parent :

```
export class ParentClass {
    constructor() { super(); }

    open(){
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Child:

```
export class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    constructor() { super(); }

    open(message: string){
        return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this code doesn't work is simple:

```
let parent: ParentClass = new ParentClass();
parent.open();
parent = new ChildClass();
// what happens now?
parent.open();
```

After the third line of code, `parent` is still a type of `ParentClass`, so `open` call should be valid. On the other hand, it contains a `ChildClass`, so we aren't providing neccessary parameter for this method: `message: string`. It's a paradox.

If you want this code to be valid, both methods should share the same parameters.

Two tips for you:

1. Avoid inheritance. Seriously, most likely you don't need it and most likely it will only lead to problems, even if it doesn't seem like at first. Try: [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).
2. If you still want to follow this way, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12689054/6063786).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need the same signature for the method in the subclass:

```
export class ParentClass {
  constructor() { 
  }

  open(message:string){ // <-----
    return "Hello World!";
  }
}

export class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  constructor() { super(); }

  open(message: string){
    return message;
  }
}
```

Or make the parameter optional in the sub class:

```
export class ParentClass {
  constructor() { 
  }

  open(message:string){
    return "Hello World!";
  }
}

export class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  constructor() { super(); }

  open(message?: string){ // <-----
    return message;
  }
}
```

See this question:

- [Typescript child class function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025364/typescript-child-class-function-overloading)