# How to create Typescript Type Definition for same named methods

Tags: typescript, kendo-ui

I have the following definition in Typescript

```
**sample.d.ts**

declare namespace Sample {

    class Widget {
        name(): string;  // gets the name
        name(name: string): void;    // sets the name
    } 
}
```

When I create the following derived Type, I get no warnings:

```
export class BarWidget extends Sample.Widget {

    public name(): string {
        return '';
    }
}
```

However, when I create the following Type, I get a Typescript error:

```
export class FooWidget extends Sample.Widget {

    public name(name: string): void {

    }
}
```

The error message is:

> Class 'FooWidget' incorrectly extends base class 'Widget'.  Types of
>   property 'name' are incompatable. Type '(name: string ) => void' is
>   not assignable to type '{ (): string; (name: string): void;}'

## Update:

This question relates to support for libraries such as kendo.ui:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/kendo-ui/kendo-ui.d.ts#L3373

In that code file, the value property of the DropDownList needs to be set and get'ted using the following syntax:

```
let foo = dd.value();
dd.value('new value');
```

My final solution was to change the definition in kendo.ui.d.ts to:

```
declare namespace Sample {
    class Widget {
        name(name?: string):string
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript cannot do all of the same overloading as other typed languages (e.g. Java).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212625/typescript-function-overloading).

In order to overload this you have to use TypeScript's bizarre multi-function definition which is described in more detail in the question I linked to.

```
declare namespace Sample {

    class Widget {
        name():string;
        name(name:string):void;
    }

}

export class BarWidget extends Sample.Widget {

    private _name:string;

    name():string;
    name(name:string):void;
    name(name?:string):string {
        if(name) {
            this._name = name;
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That works outside of the ambient namespace.

Using the amended sample gives an error message: 'an accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context'

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  This would work but it doesn't technically meet the requirement as it changes the underlying definition of name from a method to a property.

I've added an Issue on the Typescript repo for this:  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9907

Comment: refer to my final comments here for additional context: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9907

Comment: Ok, I did a bit more research and came up with a solution that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help... I ended up going with: 
`
class Widget {
    name(name?: any): any;
} 
`

Comment: At least change those `any` to `string`?

Comment: I had the any return to cover void.  I could probably do: `name(name?: string):string|void;`

Comment: A void function returns undefined.  You can return undefined from a function with return type of string in the same way you could return null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118119/discussion-between-digory-and-pace).