# Function Overloading in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is function overloading not supported in TypeScript?

I have these two functions:

```
checkCredits() {
   // my code
}

checkCredits(header: any) {
    // my code
}
```

And I call the second function like this:

```
this.checkCredits(this.myObject);
```

When compiling in vs code I get these errors:
Supplied Parameters do not match any signature of call target.
Duplicate function implementation.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689763/typescript-duplicate-function-implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloading in typescript is done by  using *optional parameters*.

```
checkCredits(header?: any) {
    // my code
}
```

Now you can call:

```
this.checkCredits(this.myObject);
```

and

```
this.checkCredits();
```

Downside you have the logic in the same function.You can check the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5658)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @Rich you can also do it [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Functions.md#overloads) way. But didnt seem necessary in your example