# How to overload method in TypeScript?

Tags: function, oop, typescript, overloading

I have a method which is taking object's parameters in the signature. I want to pass the object instead of to many parameters and on the other hand, I don't want to change the existing method's signature because it's being used already at multiple places. so basically I want both the methods. But when I'm trying to write code, it gives me error`Duplicate function implementation`.

```
    getSearchData(fetchData: FetchData,languageCode: string, sorting: string, maxResultCount: number, skipCount: number): Observable<PagedResultDtoOfFetchData> {

    getSearchData(dataLevel: number, codeType: number, dataCode: string, descLong: string, languageCode: string, dataParent: string, sorting: string, maxResultCount: number, skipCount: number): Observable<PagedResultDtoOfFetchData> {
```

FYI `dataLevel, codeType, dataCode, descLong, dataParent` are properties of `fetchData`.

Comment: Documentation -
 https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212625/typescript-function-overloading)

Comment: @gsamaras that's why I accepted your answer. You cannot force anybody to upvote. And you have copied other's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript is able to overload functions, but it has some particularities in contrast with other OOP languages, such as C++. Looking ar the [ref](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) and despite the fact that your methods have a different number of arguments, I could avoid the compiler errros by doing this:

```
class FunOverloadClass {
    getSearchData(dataLevel: number, codeType: number, dataCode: string, descLong: string, languageCode: string, dataParent: string, sorting: string, maxResultCount: number, skipCount: number): Observable<PagedResultDtoOfFetchData>;
    getSearchData(fetchData: FetchData, languageCode: string, sorting: string, maxResultCount: number, skipCount: number): Observable<PagedResultDtoOfFetchData>;

    getSearchData(stringOrNumberParameter: any, secondParam: any, thirdParam: any, fourthParam: any, fifthParam: any, dataParent?: string, sorting?: string, maxResultCount?: number, skipCount?: number): string {
        if (stringOrNumberParameter && typeof stringOrNumberParameter == "number")
            alert("Variant #1: numberParameter = " + stringOrNumberParameter);
        else
            alert("Variant #1: stringParameter = " + stringOrNumberParameter);
    }
}
```

where I used `dataParent?: string`, where the `?:` operator specifies that the parameter named `dataParent` of type `string` is *optional*.