# How can i check param is undefined in typescript generic

Tags: typescript

look this

```
class Demo<T> {
  get<K extends keyof T>(key?: K): K extends undefined ? Partial<T> : T[K] {
    const res: Partial<T> = {}
    if (key) {
      return res[key]
    } else {
      return res
    }
  }
}
```

This code does not work

I whant:

- if key == undefined, return `Partial<T>`
- esle return `T[K]`

How can i do this?

Comment: You need to check out `function overloading`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212625/typescript-function-overloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function get<T, K extends keyof T>(source: T, key: K): T[K]
function get<T>(source: T, key: undefined): Partial<T>
function get<T>(source: T): Partial<T>
function get<T, K extends keyof T>(source: T, key?: K): T[K] | Partial<T> {
  if (key === undefined) {
    return source
  }
  return source[key]
}

let a = get({ a: 1, b: 2 }, "a")
let b = get({ a: 1, b: 2 }, undefined)
let c = get({ a: 1, b: 2 })
```

function overload is what you need in this situation [Function Overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloadshttps://)