# Override function with both list and object as argument in Typescript

Tags: typescript, parameters, arguments, overriding

Can someone explain me why the first override's signature is not compatible with the implementation signature?

I want to have a function that takes both standard list arguments as well as "named" arguments in the form of an object.

I saw it done e.g. in [`react-query`](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query)'s `useQuery` hook. I had a look at their type definitions and they seem to be doing pretty much the same as I do.

Here's my attempt:

```js
interface Args {
  readonly a: string;
  readonly b?: boolean;
}

function foo(args: Args): number;
function foo(...args: [Args['a'], Args['b']?]): number;
function foo(a: string, b?: boolean): number { /* IMPLEMENTATION */ }
```

I get

> `This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature. ts(2394)`

error.

I get that object as an argument is something different than a list of arguments, so I don't really get how it actually works in `react-query`.

From inspection of their code however, they seem to define types (in `*.d.ts` file) of their `useQuery` export in similar way (see [`types/index.d.ts`](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/master/types/index.d.ts)) and the exported implementation seems to be just spreading the arguments:

[`src/useQuery.js`](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/master/src/useQuery.js):

```
...
export function useQuery(...args) {
...
```

As spread is not possible in TS if the argument is not of an Array type, I'm not sure how to simulate this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final function in an overload list in TypeScript is the implementation function and isn't recognized as a possible signature for the function call. The implementation should be able to account for the shape of all the listed overload signatures but TypeScript is only looking at those overload signatures (and not the final implementation call) when type checking.

The following is likely what you're aiming for:

```js
function foo(args: Args): number;
function foo(args: string, b?: boolean): number 
function foo(args: Args | string, b?: boolean): number { /* IMPLEMENTATION */ }
```

#### Sources:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html
-- Last paragraph on that page explains this behaviour

[TypeScript function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212625/typescript-function-overloading) --  More detailed explanation

Comment: Of course! This is correct. Just to elaborate on the impact of this: I need to split the logic for each possible arguments type in the actual implementation. E.g. use attributes from `args` if an object is passed, or use `args` as if it was string `a` otherwise.

Comment: Also I suppose I don't need the 2nd override as it provides the same interface as the 3rd one. (?)

Comment: That's correct, the 2nd signature was unnecessary and I've removed it from the answer. If you only need to be able to differentiate between a first parameter of type `Args` and a string, the answer should now do the trick. TypeScript will take the arguments you pass in and go from top to bottom checking which signature they match, then executing the implementation when it's found it.