# Typescript, different function arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript, preact

Inside my Preact application i use [unistore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unistore) for global state management. It all works fine except that my typescript interface is not working. This is because the actions (resolvers) are having an extra argument.

My `incrementBy` action is getting two arguments. The first one is the current state and the second one is the amount to increase the count by.

```
// Inside action (resolver)
incrementBy: (state, num): State => {
  return { ...state, count: state.count + num };
};
```

But when i call the function i only need to specify the amount to increase by:

```
// Inside component
<button onClick={() => incrementBy(8)}>
  Increase by 8
</button>
```

Current interface (this works for the component but (obviously) not inside the action):

```
interface Actions {
  incrementBy(num: number): State;
}
```

How can i make a single interface which works for both, so i dont have to specify multiple interfaces for every action.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include a bit more of your code, but I'm wondering whether your code needs a little bit of a refactor to achieve what you want, are you trying to follow this example here https://www.npmjs.com/package/unistore and convert it into typescript?

Comment: Can you show the entire code where you render the component? Because if I understand correctly, `incrementBy` gets injected, it's not exactly the same as the one declared in the actions. (I don't know unistore but this is what I understood from your link)

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel Yess that's what i realised as well, because it gets injected/connected it is a different function as the one declared in the actions. I switched to using different interfaces for this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably implement something like this:

```
export interface IIncrementParams {
  state?: State;
  num?: number;
}

interface IActions {
  incrementBy(params: IIncrementParams): State;
}
```

Which would allow you to do:

```
incrementBy({num: 8});
incrementBy({state: someState});
incrementBy({state: someState, num: 8});
```

---

Option 2 is you could provide multiple signatures:

```
interface IActions {
  incrementBy(num: number): State;
  incrementBy(state: State, num: number): State;
}
```

[TypeScript function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212625/typescript-function-overloading)

Comment: Yess this kinda worked, but instead of multiple interfaces i use a partial. Which does the same trick