# How to enforce strict checking for method overloading in typescript?

Tags: typescript, overloading, typescript-typings, strict

I would like to enforce a strict check for my overloaded method in a class like:

```js
type NO_PARAM = 'noParam' | 'nop';
type ONE_PARAM = 'oneParam' | 'getOne';
type ONE_PARAM_PLUS = 'oneAndMoreParam';

class Caller {
    get(type: NO_PARAM): Promise<string>;
    get(type: ONE_PARAM, arg: string): Promise<string>;
    get(type: ONE_PARAM_PLUS , arg0: string, ...args: string[]): Promise<string>;

    async get(type: NO_PARAM | ONE_PARAM | ONE_PARAM_PLUS, ...args: string[]): Promise<string> {
    // async get(type: string, ...args: string[]): Promise<string> { // Alternative
       // implementation;
       return `${type} called`;
    }
}

const obj = new Caller();

obj.get('noParam') // ok
obj.get('oneParam', 'foo') // ok
obj.get('oneAndMoreParam', 'foo') // ok
obj.get('oneAndMoreParam', 'foo', 'bar') // ok

obj.get('noParam', 'foo', 'bar') // should not pass typescript checking
obj.get('oneAndMoreParam')  // should not pass typescript checking
```

any idea ?

The closed stackoverflow question is: [TypeScript function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212625/typescript-function-overloading)

Thank you.

Comment: Just copied your code in the [playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play). It already seems to work. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: So the issue should come from my tsconfig.json. checking in progress....

Answer (score 0):

thx to Hassan Naqvi, I found the issue:

to match my original code I should change the 3 first line to:

```js
const p1 = ['noParam', 'nop'] as const;
const p2 = ['oneParam', 'getOne'];
const p3 = ['oneAndMoreParam'];

type NO_PARAM = typeof p1[number];
type ONE_PARAM = typeof p2[number];
type ONE_PARAM_PLUS = typeof p3[number];
```

In my case I forgot to add 2 missing as const.

```js
const p1 = ['noParam', 'nop'] as const;
const p2 = ['oneParam', 'getOne'] as const;
const p3 = ['oneAndMoreParam'] as const;
```

fix the issue.