# Make return type of function depends on its arguments with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that returns a promise which can be either of 2 types:

```
async profilesAll(
    ids: readonly number[],
    profileType: ProfileType.Staff | ProfileType.Pupil,
  ): Promise<(DatabaseSchema.staffProfiles | DatabaseSchema.pupilProfiles)[]> {
   // lots of logic here
}
```

Elsewhere I'm calling this function. `otherFunction`'s return type is an array of `DatabaseSchema.pupilProfiles`

```
const otherFunction = () => {
    const results = await ctx.models.room.profilesAll(
        [root.id],
        ProfileType.Pupil,
      );
    return results;
}
```

TypeScript throws an error as it believes the return type can be `DatabaseSchema.staffProfiles` or `DatabaseSchema.pupilProfiles`. However in reality the logic within `profilesAll` prevents this.

How can I remove this error? Can I make `profilesAll`'s return type depend on the `profileType` argument? I looked at conditional types but I can only see examples of them extending types, not using function arguments as I need.

Comment: You have tu use a generic method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function/method overloading for this declaration.

## Method

```typescript
class Foo {
  //option 1:
  async profilesAll(ids: readonly number[], profileType: ProfileType.Staff): Promise<DatabaseSchema.staffProfiles[]>; 
  //option 2:
  async profilesAll(ids: readonly number[], profileType: ProfileType.Pupil): Promise<DatabaseSchema.pupilProfiles[]>; 
  //implementation:
  async profilesAll(ids: readonly number[], profileType: ProfileType.Staff | ProfileType.Pupil): Promise<(DatabaseSchema.staffProfiles | DatabaseSchema.pupilProfiles)[]> {
      if (profileType === ProfileType.Staff) return getStaff(ids);
      
      return getPupils(ids);
  }
}
```

Note that you need the overloaded signatures first, then and the third implementation signature should be a merge of them. [See more on overloading here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212625/typescript-function-overloading).

This will then allow you to make type safe calls:

```typescript
declare const instance: Foo;
//OK:
const pupils = await instance.profilesAll([1, 2, 3], ProfileType.Pupil);
//OK:
const staff  = await instance.profilesAll([1, 2, 3], ProfileType.Staff);
//Error - return type is not pupilProfiles:
const wrong: DatabaseSchema.pupilProfiles[]  = await instance.profilesAll([1, 2, 3], ProfileType.Staff);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTDOEMFsAcBsFMAEAXAntepEDMD2AnFACyQgGsldtil4APKOeAKADspNpwBjJAEXDJwAI3Ch4AZW4lI4RAG9miZYnrQCyFOlJDs2AAr4qASwRYAvAsRKVtiLHD5UALkSsArpGHx8AGmu2tgAm8Fz4yJDwrMiuoMj4xqwA5jbKAL6pqnTq4VoYiNDu0KaGJmaIloqBKkn44CEAggBuPuBJ8K4eXj4A3Jm2qPCOnZ7e+H22GRnMIdwO+EjY7qzcyMa4rIjtyBK62AAUxkGgrgv1G7CobqM+ANoAugCUiK6IpZDG4gA8AkKi4lIZOAAHRxcB6UrYUyYB4APj6s3mi2Wq3Wm22+iKplAh2OpyGQQuVy6Ywej1e70+8B+ghEYkk0ngsmBhWKsEh0NAcL6zGYUU8byMUIQABVtFZduDsP5MWzENM5mIsAAxXC4BQ2EC4aBrDaIACMzhsYlQKwKQs5DVgsFxJ0QZ0JrEu126+Ae-mgFtF2lcHO9GGBkr05MFuA+31+dIBjOZYIhXph93hAUQWp1aMQACYjcoTWbPWVMFabUc7Q6iS7SfcPQmxRhfbXtMDZaYQ5SI7T-gygSyseyE1ykz0UyBjDAEJFooI0TnEHnuObC6Bi7b8ecncSbm7q4vhfA6x1Q3uD4G9ogAD5H6EnluwNtGcPU-aRruApkguMGAcXxAv+lv5lWRKAdHjhDVqmMah9gLY9xXMeCr39eBTylZ4FmQdx8HReAdj2W1Hh5ap0Mw7DkFvHFSwImwpl5RFHCQbgNjiRBEjBFZD1VXA+nnHAUV1TZZESRB9meKpU2AAB5ABpWdGNYZigNgCw5wAd3AYxNFYoR2JZAcV1ufV-EzfwAGYdz9fcm1vKjlBAaTZKYzRP2USxwDUjSWPk7TeF0pd9MMrNTPMxsAyDbAbPEgBRfAjEIABae0cJIvIkE+NxcE0RSLJOGw5OYlSjGSVw-2jHssoHB4XNU9TNK88AdJgy1rX2AyjKCmUQuQsKqLSIA)

## Function

Using functions and overloading them, is analogous but you wouldn't have a class in that case:

```typescript
//option 1:
async function profilesAll(ids: readonly number[], profileType: ProfileType.Staff): Promise<DatabaseSchema.staffProfiles[]>;
//option 2:
async function profilesAll(ids: readonly number[], profileType: ProfileType.Pupil): Promise<DatabaseSchema.pupilProfiles[]>;
//implementation:
async function profilesAll(ids: readonly number[], profileType: ProfileType.Staff | ProfileType.Pupil): Promise<(DatabaseSchema.staffProfiles | DatabaseSchema.pupilProfiles)[]> {
    if (profileType === ProfileType.Staff) return getStaff(ids);
    
    return getPupils(ids);
}

/* ... */

//OK:
const pupils = await profilesAll([1, 2, 3], ProfileType.Pupil);
//OK:
const staff  = await profilesAll([1, 2, 3], ProfileType.Staff);
//Error - return type is not pupilProfiles:
const wrong: DatabaseSchema.pupilProfiles[]  = await profilesAll([1, 2, 3], ProfileType.Staff);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-OkAxnMsEQ41mbnMRXKtGIABMmu1uqWKwNBRjmFN5qOlutRPtpPuztz7o6geFbp9stMAcpIdp-wZQJZWPZua593h8eAxhgCEi0UEaLToB13D1WaTLtroHzFvx51txJujvLOddVc9lZ9fuoAB8a9Cq8CG7Am0Zg9T9qG24CmSCowYe4hT4-6c-maySj2jxwgomTGNQ+wLue4rmDBZ7ehgvp7M8CzIO4+DovAOx7BajwTComQoWhGHIFeOKFrhzDTOmM6ZqiqqyIkiD7M8VSICAADyADSmrKNwGxxAUXYWIg4AAO7gMYmiQWYy63Gq-jJv4ADM25enWCFXhRygcdxNh8awAlvsolhiRJUk9rJ8kpspqkHghR5aWxwAAKL4EYhAALRWphRF5EgnxuLgUldmpJx6fxmiiUYySuN+4Ydv+3aur2xkieJkk7oulkKTZMp2fAiFShRaRAA)

Answer (score 1):

You should use overloads:

```
async function profilesAll(ids: number[], profileType: ProfileType.Pupil): Promise<(DatabaseSchema.pupilProfiles)[]>
async function profilesAll(ids: number[], profileType: ProfileType.Staff): Promise<(DatabaseSchema.staffProfiles)[]>
async function profilesAll(
  ids: readonly number[],
  profileType: ProfileType.Staff | ProfileType.Pupil,
): Promise<DatabaseSchema.staffProfiles[]> | Promise<DatabaseSchema.pupilProfiles[]> {
   // lots of logic here
}
```

Comment: I get a bunch of "red squiggles" in my IDE when I try and add this. It looks like the syntax is not correct?

Comment: @Evanss yes, it has some syntax error because I copied your snippet and it is missing `function` keyword, let me edit the answer

Comment: @Evanss, I edited the answer and fixed the syntax errors, if you have any more red squiggles, I can't tell the reason without seeing the rest of the code, because the current snippet is correct

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can modify the return type based on the input parameter dynamically. However, in this specific case, you can specify the return type of your `otherFunction` by explicitly defining it.

```
const otherFunction = (): DatabaseSchema.pupilProfiles => { ... }
```

This way your `otherFunction` return type is no longer `DatabaseSchema.staffProfiles | DatabaseSchema.pupilProfiles` but `DatabaseSchema.pupilProfiles` only.