# How to define a dynamic generic constraint in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a abstract base class with a generic type parameter like this:

```js
abstract class Base<T> {
  constructor(protected value: T) {}
}
```

I inherit multiple classes from the base. For example:

```js
class TBase extends Base<number> {
  constructor(value: number) { 
    super(value); 
  }
}

class XBase extends Base<string> {
  constructor(value: string) { 
    super(value); 
  }
}
```

Now I want to write a factory function that returns a new Base based on my input properties:

```js
type ValidTypes = 'string' | 'integer' | 'decimal' | 'boolean' | 'datetime';

type validFor<T> = T extends 'string' | 'datetime'
  ? string
  : T extends 'integer' | 'decimal'
  ? number
  : T extends 'boolean'
  ? boolean
  : never;

function getBase<T extends ValidTypes, P extends validFor<T>>(type: T, value: P): Base<P> {
 switch(type) {
   case 'number': new TBase(coerceNumber(value)); break;
   ...
 } 
}
```

When passing 'string' as first parameter, the second can only be of type string. For 'decimal', type P can only be a number.

But I have two problems. When calling the function like this:

```js
getBase('string', '5');
```

It works, but it says that the signature is

```
function getBase<'string', '5'>(type: 'string', value: '5'): Base<'5'>
```

It don't understand why it's not resolving to string but instead to the value of value?

The other problem is, that when I return a new TBase() it states that it could also be a string or boolean:

"'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | boolean'."

I searched a lot about this, but couldn't get around it. Could someone explain to me why excactly this happens? Even when i explicit cast it to a Base it throws the error (return new TBase() as Base)

Another approach I tried was with using function overloads, but this looks kinda weird and not right:

```js
getBase(type: 'decimal' | 'integer', value: number): Base<number>
getBase(type: 'string' | 'datetime', value: string): Base<string>
getBase(type: 'boolean', value: boolean): Base<boolean>
getBase(type: ValidTypes, value: number | boolean | string): Base<number | boolean | string> {
  ...
}
```

I want to something like this:

```js
getBase('string', 'thisMustBeAString'); // => Base<string>;
getBase('decimal', 54 /* Must be a number */) // => Base<number>;
```

What am I missing? I'm quiet struggling with this for a long time now.. Thanks in advance

Edit:

[Playground Link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/FDCGCMGcBcCdQMbQAQIDakpZAhTBTAHgBUA+ZAb2GVQHsA7GWAVyVtgAoAHWW6fJPgAmyAG6g0zfAC5kxAJSUAvsBXB0mbMTyR8yfAA9+9Idh1F6zALbh8sclRoIGTVtHYdxkmcks27ihTI1DTIkMxcdp4SUvIA3ME0KmoaWMgAGub6RvgmZgSETACW9ADmDiHOjHBuHl5SssVlgYmh4ZGc9fjxrckg0ACekcgAahJFQsRD+NgAvMgA5E2lC8gAPosl-KV2qxsLQgJFVhJ7i+C0tGj4oPRnB6D80Mf4C3H902LjQgBi7CTkebEbLGUyLZb3ISPfDPKyvEIAfjCcBKpRCsmBhlB2AWW3wO1gkKOJzQC0Rvmstlg6LkINyYIWFyuNzu5KZ11uNPo+FEdnewAAZsx6Egigw6HYEPgAHKUqJdWTCgDW9FoAHd6PJZH4qZQQjQigLkBwAIRFSDS0DS7igWC6H5oWiPaLeZCYZGwVHyRQAMh9yDNFqtHFl-k6MW63r1oRjyFgMOYsHoyFDVJdsXeMaU+jQumjsZo8egieTAAZM6FkvyAPTV5AAQS4PCdCAAFsgGPgQEKRc9xTtoOYSHS8qNvlNIpAADTIAAKI7BXgmf1gANIHEGkQxM4Vc61uAKs4qYTVRWgbY300C+oQBEWOt2siLJd8+DVcnMHGckplcvD3m9BJazkVtzWQAVQCKXNkFsW9mDzM86GYNARAkSBaBgvRQA9VEO1gGDLg5egEX1Q4IOQ6BZGgVteHfbl3wAUVgXhOHiahs1UEAQGAxtm0QdtoDVWhu2FUV+xhHBP03HwDmJU51k2ehtl2HcI21P99yHB97EFUS+2TAdJIIS8t3BFEykhaFYVeVTvEaczSk0gpllIXTezFAyJKk6ZZEZQiWQWWyGgI5lbic3RCHZFlXJ7MTPMHbzTLGNAJgnGYgp8bSFKi24FOWcKLD-bL-NyjYXPzGhIFPc9WxM7oKtjW881xJT8UfOMEyTV9320Yzv1gKVU3lCNAP1WMyNACiqJo9VuuQJiWI4Nis2CNRgOIGZoEgEBDOMpYHMCxZsIhHpgNmchYv05BdoigAiZZbpnW7joc2712k2R7tejLPpez0ylugrCGenCAdc4BDM-fb-pWGcAFZTrrAARWgZl8PhkCE2AlUwuC8y6ZArHglBbFBtFIb2qEnheQ6Fj+1EFkR5AAHV2CVbBYMmvMqZhF5X2EbB6bKIA)

Comment: Please share `coerceNumber`
Unable to reproduce your code.
Could you please share it in typescript playground?

Comment: @captain-yossarian coerceNumber is actually coerceNumberProperty from @angular/cdk/coercion and coerces a input value to be a number. I added a similar implemention to the playground (link in the post)

Comment: try to remove return type from `getBase` function. Please let me know if it is ok for you

Comment: @captain-yossarian Just removing the type would just resolve to TBase | XBase, which isn't really what I want

Answer (score 0):

I tried very hard to get your first approach to work in a fully type-safe manner without casts, but failed.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64892817/make-return-type-of-function-depends-on-its-arguments-with-typescript) also deals with return types whose types depend on argument types, and several answers suggest to use overloading. As you've already found, that's one way to solve it – although the return type of your implementation should not be `Base<number | string | boolean>` but rather `Base<number> | Base<string> | Base<boolean>`.

If you're okay with changing the call syntax a bit, you can do this and still remain fully type safe:

```js
// Deliberately leaving this untyped, so we get the most specific inferred type possible.
const factories = {
  'integer': (value: number) => new TBase(value) as Base<number>,
  'string': (value: string) => new XBase(value) as Base<string>,
}

const a: Base<string> = factories['string']('thisMustBeAString');
const b: Base<number> = factories['integer'](54);
const c: Base<number> = factories['integer']('thisWillNotCompile');
const d: Base<number> = factories['string']('neitherWillThis');
const e: Base<string> = factories[a.value]('norWillThis');
```

Some ways to extract types from this map:

```js
// Extract the names of the types: 'integer' | 'string'.
type TypeName = keyof typeof factories;

// Extract the type of the factory function, for example (value: number) => Base<number>.
type FactoryType<T extends TypeName> = typeof factories[T];

// Extract the type of argument that goes into the factory.
type FactoryArgumentType<T extends TypeName> = Parameters<FactoryType<T>>[0];

// Extract the factory's return type.
// Currently always equal to its argument type, but it doesn't need to be.
type FactoryReturnType<T extends TypeName> = ReturnType<FactoryType<T>>;
```

Using these, you can in fact implement `getBase` in a rather ugly way:

```js
function getBase<T extends TypeName>(type: T, value: FactoryArgumentType<T>): FactoryReturnType<T> {
  return factories[type](value as never) as FactoryReturnType<T>;
}
```

I don't quite understand why the strange `value as never` is needed to make the compiler accept this, but it emits the right code in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this in the morning and answer afterwards