# Typescript Method overloading for different type of parameters but same response

Tags: typescript, methods, overloading

I need to overload a method using TypeScript.

**FooModel** has 6 parameters, but 2 string parameters are the only mandatory params. So instead of creating a **FooModel** every time I want to use the **myMethod**, I want to overload **myMethod** and create the **FooModel** once in there and then the rest of the logic before return.

I've tried this based on what I found so far online, but it I get the following error:

```
TS2394: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.
```

The solutions for this error is not compatable with my method

```
    static async myMethod(model: FooModel): Promise<BarResult>
    static async myMethod(inputText: string, outputText: string): Promise<BarResult>{
         //implementation;
      return new BarResult(); //Different content based on the inputs
    }
```

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212625/typescript-function-overloading)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Problem

From TypeScript's documentation:

> #### Overload Signatures and the Implementation Signature
>
> This is a common source of confusion. Often people will write code like this and not understand why there is an error:

```
function fn(x: string): void;
function fn() {
  // ...
}
// Expected to be able to call with zero arguments
fn();
^^^^
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
```

> Again, the signature used to write the function body can’t be “seen” from the outside.
>
> The signature of the implementation is not visible from the outside. When writing an overloaded function, you should always have two or more signatures above the implementation of the function.
>
> The implementation signature must also be compatible with the overload signatures. For example, these functions have errors because the implementation signature doesn’t match the overloads in a correct way:

```
function fn(x: boolean): void;
// Argument type isn't right
function fn(x: string): void;
         ^^
This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.

function fn(x: boolean) {}
```

```
function fn(x: string): string;
// Return type isn't right
function fn(x: number): boolean;
         ^^
This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.

function fn(x: string | number) {
  return "oops";
}
```

– [TypeScript documentation on overload and implementation signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature)

In your case you've defined the following overload signature:

```
static async myMethod(model: FooModel): Promise<BarResult>
```

But the implementation signature has no overlap. The first argument in your implementation signature is `string` while the overload is `FooModel` while the second argument in the implementation signature is `string` while the overload is `undefined`.

```
static async myMethod(inputText: string, outputText: string): Promise<BarResult>{
```

## Solution

Turn your current implementation signature into an overload and add an implementation signature which is compatible with both your overloads:

```
class Foo {
  static async myMethod(model: FooModel): Promise<BarResult>;
  static async myMethod(inputText: string, outputText: string): Promise<BarResult>;
  static async myMethod(modelOrInputText: string | FooModel, outputText?: string): Promise<BarResult>{
   //implementation;
    return new BarResult(); //Different content based on the inputs
  }
}
```

– [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0Fl0BMIA2yA3gL4BQ5CBcAzrcgEJxQBKEtArgWCRVTXppMJcsmS0wcMMATI6ATxByAtgqwQwACzwAKFXkIAuYdkMEAlCYAKUdCuC0IAHmZsO3MAD4A3GIlSMnKKyshqGtp6oAAOnGAAKhAAHmAmklCgAOYANMjocbEJyakBGSCZVsi29o4ubuxcPL7+ktKy8rRKquqaOrj65gDyUACSIIWJKWlgZZnIAD6mOPgEuflgE8UA-NOzldUOTq4sDZ5exP7IAPRXwCrRBBAqEOBt6CB+4uJQmpxQIMgQBAAO5ME4eHi6Cw+a5XAAiwBgMGgL14CHekHAyAARnQILg8gDtCgYnFaP4KKQgA)