# TypeScript type discriminated unions in function arguments

Tags: typescript, types

The type of the second argument of the function depends on the string value of the first argument. I'd like to get something like this:

```
    async action (name: 'create', args: { table: string, object: StorageObject }): Promise<StorageObject>;
    async action (name: 'createOrUpdate', args: { table: string, query: StorageQuery, object: StorageObject }): Promise<Array<StorageObject>>;
    async action (name: 'read', args: { table: string, query: StorageQuery }): Promise<Array<StorageObject>>;
    async action (name: 'update', args: { table: string, query: StorageQuery, object: StorageObject }): Promise<Array<StorageObject>>;
    async action (name: 'delete', args: { table: string, query: StorageQuery }): Promise<Array<StorageObject>> {
        ...
    }
```

Currently, I've got: `TS2394: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.`

Comment: You need n + 1 signatures when you use overloads - the n overloads plus the 1 implementation signature: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Method overloading for different type of parameters but same response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69674774/typescript-method-overloading-for-different-type-of-parameters-but-same-response)

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing an overloading, the implementation signature need to be compatible with every of the overloads. Btw this last signature won't be exposed in the `.d.ts`

```
  async action(name: 'create', args: { table: string, object: StorageObject }): Promise<StorageObject>;
  async action(name: 'createOrUpdate', args: { table: string, query: StorageQuery, object: StorageObject }): Promise<Array<StorageObject>>;
  async action(name: 'read', args: { table: string, query: StorageQuery }): Promise<Array<StorageObject>>;
  async action(name: 'update', args: { table: string, query: StorageQuery, object: StorageObject }): Promise<Array<StorageObject>>;
  async action(name: 'delete', args: { table: string, query: StorageQuery }): Promise<Array<StorageObject>>;

  // The actual implementation that needs to cover every case above 
  async action(name: 'create' | 'delete' | 'update' | 'read' | 'createOrUpdate', args: { table: string, query: StorageQuery, object: StorageObject }): Promise<Array<StorageObject> | StorageObject> {
    if (name === 'create' || name === 'delete') {
      return Promise.resolve(new StorageObject())
    }

    return Promise.resolve([new StorageObject()])
  }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=4&pln=6&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwMoBcD2MoHMQB5AIwCtxN4BveAXwFgAoUJORaVDHPQgRQCuIGAE8a9ZsyRcAYtmw1JTePBQiAdmFVhMAS2zqAFOqgBbEAC54AcjBwomENYA0qmPmRXamKCQiX4ZEwYXXV8V2xySissXAJiKJ16AEorAAUYbFNdZBAAHljeBIodAD4AbmYVNU1tPQNjMwDbe0ciGABVAAdgBydXWA8veB8-AKCQsNcARyFRGJ54wWERCMTMBbjCUhKqOlT4DKyc-IBBGDwRAsXt9dKKqtVkDS0oHX0jE3Mra3tgFzcQ3Eo38VgmoXC8FmK02RWWohS6Uy2VyeXOl2uW2KlHulWUTxedQ+jW+NgEPT6AMGnmBvlBgWCEJmcxEsKWLLWuzZt12iMOyJOaIuUCuhXiOxxD3xNVe7waX2aoH8jip7hp3jp40ZUyhLO5IHhYn2SOOqPRIsxRQlZSljwA9Hb4AAVAAWCDemAEUAg8F0pi6-nM6h89XUIxdDng6hAIGAaBwiGwADdhPAQCmEWAUO6SMmEI8ZUT5U0fnYQJT4AAfGxKkAqqtkin16u-cv-BstcttTpN-qA9UjTVg7WQ6HzbhYw2c6ITq3rPlHFFnYWim7YsoNsU8nGKfEqXQAM3gJIQAF5zzYyxXK9WFfBz6eayBlU5kruVB-4HBPTAw4uTgAdHAyDYBAKbGCAADus7iushjJMkjwqIwTBIV+dYCL+-KmiAQEgCBYEgIYADa0bQVu66YPBAC6iH4ihdBAA)