# Sinon unable to stub overloaded methods

Tags: typescript, sinon

Given the following class:

```
class Foo {
  public bar(): Bar;
  public bar(string): Bar;
}
```

I want to stub only the first `bar()` method, how should I do that or is there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

### Not exactly

You can't do this. Typescript's overloaded methods don't exist at run time - they compile down to a single method.

From [the typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html):

> TypeScript can only resolve a function call to a single overload

See this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61711290/790070) to a different question for some discussion.

There's also [this blog post](https://kevinkreuzer.medium.com/typescript-method-overloading-c256dd63245a) which has the following example:

```
    public getHero(name: string): Hero {
        return /* some code here */
    }

    public getHero(name: string, skill: string): Hero {
        return /* some other code here */
    }
```

A breakpoint in the second function is hit when the first function is called, because Typescript has compiled away the two functions into one.

---

### A workaround

However if you need exactly this behaviour - you can make a complex stub that will allow you to call the underlying implementation in some cases using `wrappedMethod` and `callsFake` ([documentation link here](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v12.0.1/stubs)):

```
        sinon
            .stub(foo, "bar");

         foo.bar.callsFake(function mockBar(maybeString?: string) {
             if (string === undefined) { /* stub behaviour */}
             else { return foo.bar.wrappedMethod(maybeString) }                
         });
```

---

### An aside

As an aside, I would advise against complex stubbing, because now you are in a situation where it would be appropriate to write tests for your tests - in my view, it would be better to refactor the code so that this kind of stubbing is not necessary.

Comment: When I do `sinon.stub(foo, "bar").withArgs()`, I got `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0` error at the `withArgs()` line.

Comment: @JackGuo Quite right. I've updated the answer

Comment: it still doesn't work. I noticed that whenever I use callsFake in this scenario, it gets stuck in an infinite loop at line sinon/proxy-invoke.js:50:47. I tried the withArgs() approach again with @ts-ignore, but it seems to be invoked for the bar(string) method as well.

Comment: Problem solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70544581/cloud-function-unit-test-mock-new-document-id/70544860#70544860