# cloud function unit test mock new document ID

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, sinon

For Firestore cloud function TypeScript unit tests, I want to mock `doc().id`, but *not* `doc('path')`. How should I do that?

```
admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc().id // I only want to mock this one

admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc('1')
```

I tried doing the following in sinon. But it gets stuck in an infinite loop at `sinon/proxy-invoke.js:50:47`:

```
const collection = admin.firestore().collection('posts');
sinon.stub(collection. 'doc').callsFake(path => 
   path === undefined ? mock : collection.doc(path)
);
sinon.stub(admin.firestore(), 'collection')
  .callThrough()
  .withArgs('posts')
  .returns(collection)
```

I also tried the following. But the `doc(documentPath: string)` method seems to be stubbed out as well:

```
sinon.stub(collection, 'doc')
  //@ts-ignore
  .withArgs()
  .returns(mock)
```

I am open to using other mock libraries if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an infinite loop because you are recursively calling the stubbed method:

```
sinon.stub(collection, 'doc').callsFake(path => 
   path === undefined ? mock : collection.doc(path) // <- this calls the stub again
);
```

First you need to pluck the original `doc` method from the object you will stub. You also must use the traditional `function` syntax so that `this` is properly passed through to the fake callback (you should also pass it to any other functions you call as appropriate). While this `doc` function only takes a single path argument, you should get into the habit of using rest parameters to make sure you are handling all the arguments.

```
// store the raw function (make sure this only happens
// once as you don't want to stash a stubbed function)
const _originalDoc = collection.doc;

sinon.stub(collection, 'doc')
  .callsFake(function (...args) { // important! `function` not arrow function
    // In this function, `this` is an instance of CollectionReference
    return args.length = 0 || args[0] === undefined // don't forget the return
      ? mock.call(this)                // call the mocked function
      : _originalDoc.apply(this, args) // call the original with the original arguments
  });
```

If your mock also calls `collection.doc()`, make sure that you call the original function, not the stubbed one (unless intentional).

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly. I had to modify it a little:

`sinon.stub(collection, 'doc').callsFake(function (this: CollectionReference, ...args) {
      return args[0] === undefined
        ? (({ id: mockID } as unknown) as DocumentReference)
        : // eslint-disable-next-line no-invalid-this
          originalDoc.apply(this, args);
    });`

Comment: @JackGuo Why not `originalDoc.apply(this, args[0] === undefined ? [mockID] : args);`? It has the same effect, but you get the full document reference object (if you end up using the rest of the object).

Comment: Good idea. Thanks!