# How to use Typescript generic for this case to remove errors

Tags: typescript, generics

I am using an function which return random type values (string/boolean/object/undefined) based on condition passed in parameters.
On using the value returned from this method to other typed function which expect certain values they are giving error.
I think this can be solved by generics but I am not able to.

Attaching screenshot of the case and URL of typescript playground for the same.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwIZgCZwLYBUCeADgKYBKxUIyYAYpABQDWx+AXIgM5TIxgDmASkQBvAFCIJnAO4woEABaImLIWMnrEEVB2KIARAEY9rcRrPIKVJMLCpsxdnqjEuegDScIcC+wCsANgBfAG5TMy0dfXAMYmBeYgxjMLNJC0pqRGjY+IxQlM1tXT0AJiT89TSrRGK8lIiirh5+ADVUABsy8olKjL1G3j5Wjtrwwv1uEGJOrp6kCeIRjQB6JcQAKxAuRGBvRGIADztCNt0tJFnEdHwoeQHk9RjgVBA2qBMu7ssMsBe2xcDRADRLxnMgnhBdABJIYGETJZxcdj9fjBRCA0SgSCwBCIPgUIaTAz0VDsaHtAwCNSSLxgDhwE4AOjacD4xIEixWnBwukIyDgEI4HEumBQXzA6OBYFB4KhQ2KcPUCLenG4A1R6Mx0HgSDxUAJxGKxNJcspyRpdMZzNZqHZyU5dPsiF5-JcQvQGFF6XFQM59UQBlE5qgKHdOFhAF4Q5gcAQSOQvXQIPRDHpbUGufYYYhI7r9US0NHsBTQqJOaBkDdiMhLsBQRnTnAYqJAwgtgWsNh5ZH2zGiGQxYnkwBBVOhdMO4hy7O4-HtQn0Hud23NldAA)

[image: playground errors]

Comment: Interfaces in TypeScript do not start with `I`.

Comment: We can use any name for interface and adding "I" doesn't give any errors. Also can we go back to original question.

Comment: You don't need generics to solve this. If the return-type of `randomTypeReturnFunc` depends entirely on the string value of `key` then use declared overloads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212625/typescript-function-overloading

Comment: Yes, this can be solved with overloading the function return value but this is just for example, my actual function will be returning more than 100 different interfaces which is not optimal to overload.

Comment: "my actual function will be returning more than 100 different interfaces which is not optimal to overload." - **then you have a fundamentally broken software design**. You need to re-think your approach.

Comment: This function is actually calling various thrid party api's, so data is not in fixed format. Anyways thanks.

Comment: If the data from your third party api's is really totally random every time, there is no way to create a predefined type for it. You'll just have to create `type guards` to check if a certain property exists. But in reality, most API's have predefined ways that they return their data.