# How to implement overloaded function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, overloading

I have a following definition of `SRequest` object:

```js
type SRequest = {
  headers: string[];
  get(header: string): string;
  get(header: 'Set-Cookie'): string[];
}

const myReq: SRequest = {
  headers: [ 'a' ],
  get: (header: string | 'Set-Cookie'): string | string[] => {
    if (header === 'Set-Cookie') {
      return [ 'x' ];
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```

But it fails to compile. I thought with overloaded function I can use union type for different arguments but I get this error:

Error:

```
Type '(header: string | 'Set-Cookie') => string | string[]' is not assignable to type '{ (header: string): string; (header: "Set-Cookie"): string[]; }'.
  Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Comment: I feel you are doing the whole overloading wrong.
Function/method overload happens when each function or method has a different number of arguments but the same name, and the same return type.  Yours violate the conditions.

Comment: The example provided is constrained on purpose, I'm actually trying to satisfy a compiler because such a definition is provided by external library. So it's probably issue with the definitions.

However I think it's allowed to have different return type, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24222144/3056783

Comment: @KelvinUkuejubolaOritsetimeyi - that is not true. Function overloading in TypeScript allows different parameter and return types. This is more or less a common use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler only has limited ways of understanding function implementations. It basically just looks what the the type of each return statement is and creates a union of those types. In this case, that would result in `string | string[]` which conflicts with your overloads.

It probably feels like an unsatisfying solution, but forcefully silencing the error with an assertion might be the only way.

```
const myReq: SRequest = {
  headers: [ 'a' ],
  get: (header) => {
    if (header === 'Set-Cookie') {
      return [ 'x' ] as string & string[]
    }
    return '' as string & string[]
  }
}
```

The overload definition demands that the implementation must return a `string` and a `string[]` to satisfy both overloads; hence the interseciton. While not being truly type-safe, it would at least give some warnings when you would try to return a `number` for example.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygShAjgVwgZ2FAvFA3gKCigAsIBDAEwgCc0AuKDagSwDsBzAbQF0BuQqOwjAAFKUo0GTNuwCUU4Cw78iQ0eKrUGAchjCAtAGEA9sYDWzCNvmNFMnvwC++fAGNjrDFAC2IBIgZ4JFQvHAIiDRp6KE4obTJtKG4AGgE1BjFyTVlsAD48ASJmADMoTIlqbCwcXQMTc0trAqIWqGphZGpWGLiAD0TuKDI0WyV2KAAyUftuQqhnVvbgTu7tROHpjknNrlmiZ0cgA)