# Dynamically setting the return type based on the argument provided

Tags: typescript

I have 4 classes as follows:

```
class PutCommand {
   // TODO
}

class PutCommandOutput {
   // TODO
}

class DeleteCommand {
   // TODO
}

class DeleteCommandOutput {
   // TODO
}
```

I am trying to create a function that accepts `PutCommand` or `DeleteCommand` as an argument, then returns `PutCommandOutput` or `DeleteCommandOutput` based on the argument.

Initially, my function was something like this.

```
function executeCommand(command: PutCommand|DeleteCommand): PutCommandOutput|DeleteCommandOutput {
   // TODO:
}
```

but I still have to check the type of the return value after executing the function as follows:

```
const output = executeCommand(command);

if (output instance PutCommandOutput) {

} else {
   // DeleteCommandOutput
}
```

To make it more intelligent, I could change the function to something like this.

```
function executeCommand<T>(command: PutCommand|DeleteCommand): T {
   // TODO:
}
```

but I still have to explicitly pass the return type as below:

```
const output = executeCommand<DeleteCommandOutput>(command);
```

Is there a way to make the function more intelligent by dynamically changing the return type based on the argument?

Example:

```
const output = executeCommand(putCommand); // passing the instance of PutCommand so that return type is PutCommandOutput

// here I can call all the functions of PutCommandOutput
```

Comment: [method overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212625/typescript-function-overloading) should do the trick for you

Comment: The right answer here is probably going to be overloads, but could you please [edit] to make your code a [mre] without pseudocode (`instance` isn't a thing) and without empty classes (which [make for strange examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely))?  The hope is that the only issues with your example code should be the ones you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

```
function executeCommand<P extends PutCommand | DeleteCommand>(command: P) 
    : P extends PutCommand ? PutCommandOutput : DeleteCommandOutput  {
       // TODO:
    }
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Due to lack of information this the best I could do.

```js
interface PutCommand {
  type: 'put';
  payload: any;
}

interface PostCommand {
  type: 'post';
  payload: any;
}

interface PutCommandOutput {
  type: 'put';
  body: any;
}

interface PostCommandOutput {
  type: 'post';
  body: any;
}

type ReturnCommandOutput<T> =
  T extends PutCommand ? PutCommandOutput :
  T extends PostCommand ? PostCommandOutput :
  never;

function executeCommand<T>(command: T): ReturnCommandOutput<T> {
  return {
    // ...
  } as ReturnCommandOutput<T>;
}

const putCommand: PutCommand = {
  type: 'put',
  payload: {}
}

const postCommand: PostCommand = {
  type: 'post',
  payload: {}
}

const putCommandOutput = executeCommand(putCommand);
const postCommandOutput = executeCommand(postCommand);
```

[TS Playground ---> Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoFcwGED2BbPOEAE2QG8AoZZMATwAcIAuZAcns1YG4rl65aAGxxxiLIrR4BfChVCRYiFKhwBnbPkIlyvOoxbs1Ybr35CRY5BOmz50eEjSZcBIsQDymDmB3U9zNm8TagAjHGJacRBJChk5cHslNCMXLQ8vTF8aBgDDdWDkMIiomLj-ZAAlCDB0KBBUt08wbwAeABUAPmQAXl425AgAD0gSVScNV20AfnGGkibvZCY%20geGIUeT1OdIZlS3NRoyfZeoQCAA3aB4KGHQQBDBgHBBViARMCG32joAKBAOSCw2gBKFhVGp1bYLTDfLJQaq1F6UajUAD0qOQADpsbwpFYxuDEVCjt8bBR-iB1HxnADLBgJmkell-AYggAaUwCYSiFhkGRxClU%20gpWksPYMtxM5HZfSBIysDnUMzcyx82KyQU%20bzE5qZbqvd6QbY-bW04E8TV8EWTdK6nz6oZvD7G4X7G3moA)

[image]

[image]