Any short way to override a parent method in a child class?
I searched here and haven't found any way

To easily assign a type to a class method (method2: Method isn't a class method in pure sense it's an "instance" (own property) method). If it's possible I could reuse a method type in the both parent and child classes.
When you override a parent method there's no easy way to infer type of the child method, so I used Parameters<> (and I have extremely complex parameter list (with typed callbacks, etc)).
There's satisfies keyword but I don't understand how it could be applied to this case

type Method = (n: number) => number;

class A{
  method(n: number){ // <- how to type it with Method?
    return n;
  }
  method2: Method = n => n; // <- not a class method
}

class B extends A {
  method(...[n]: Parameters<A['method']>){ // <- I can't repeat 5 arguments with 10 types 
                                           // involved in a real case, any shorter version?
    return n;
  }
}

Any help how to make optimal DRY (without repeating a long method list in an interface and again in classes) typing would be appreciated.

You're looking for something like ms/TS#22063 but it's not part of the language. The workarounds are all annoying, as you've seen.

@jcalz could you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78597773/how-to-make-typecript-know-the-return-type-of-a-function-when-passing-different/78597899#78597899? i suspect the answer is wrong due involving many as

• "could you check [other answer]"? Not sure what I'm looking for there or what it has to do with this question. • "jcalz applying a type to a real class method (in prototype) isnt possible either?" I'm not sure I understand, but I doubt it can be made to work using prototypes either, since you'd need to merge into the class interface, and then you have the same problem. Method syntax and function-valued property syntax are different, and getting it to happen with methods would require some kind of thing like ms/TS#22063 which is not part of the language.
