# Functions Overloading in interface and classes - how to?

Tags: class, interface, overloading, typescript

I have this interface :

```
interface IPoint {
    getDist(): string;
    getDist(x: number): any;
}
```

and I need a class to implement it but I can't get the right syntax to implement the getDist() method
in the class..

```
class Point implements IPoint {
    // Constructor
    constructor (public x: number, public y: number) { }

    pointMethod() { }

    getDist() {
        Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
    }
    // Static member
    static origin = new Point(0, 0);
}
```

it says:

> Class 'Point' declares interface 'IPoint' but does not implement it:
>   Types of property 'getDist' of types 'Point' and 'IPoint' are
>   incompatible:Call signatures of types '() => void' and '{ (): string;
>   (x: number): any; }' are incompatible

What's the proper way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you declare the function in the class you need to decorate it with the overloads:

```
getDist(): string;
getDist(x: number): any;
getDist(x?: number): any {
    // your code
 }
```

Comment: You need not write the second declaration. It works even without that

Comment: @S.RaviKiran you need both overload declarations as you can't call the implementation on overloaded functions. You can try this out in the TypeScript Playground. http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/

Comment: @S.RaviKiran Post your example.

Comment: it works without adding the declarations but to get overloading in Visual studio auto complete you need to add overloading decelerations.

Comment: And static typing for the return values, which are different.

Answer (score 5):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12689054/139010) describes how to implement method overloading in TypeScript, and it's not pretty:

```
interface IPoint {
    getDist(): string;
    getDist(x: number): any;
}

class Point implements IPoint {
    // Constructor
    constructor (public x: number, public y: number) { }

    pointMethod() { }

    getDist(x?: number) {
         if (x && typeof x == "number") {
             return 'foo';
         } else {
             return 'bar';
         }
    }
}
```

N.B. with the particular combination of declared return types in the interface, you are limited to returning strings from `getDist`.

Comment: You mean it's not pretty just because it has the if-else typeguards?

Answer (score 3):

also you can use the default value

```
interface Foo{
    next()
    next(steps: number)
    prev()
    prev(steps: number)
}

next(steps: number = 1) {
    // ...
}

prev(steps: number = 1) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a variation on some of the above

```
class Position {
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor(x : number = 0, y : number = 0) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }    
}

class Pen {
    colour: string;

    constructor(colour: string) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }
}

class PlottingHead {
    isPenUp: boolean;
    pen: Pen;
    position: Position;

    constructor() {     
       this.penUp();
   }

   move(p: Position): void;
   move(x: number, y: number): void;
   move(x: number | Position, y?: number): void {
        if (typeof x === "number")
        {
            x = new Position(x, y);
        }
        this.penUp();
        this.position = x;
    }

    draw(x: number | Position, y?: number): void {
        if (typeof x === "number")
        {
            x = new Position(x, y);
        }
        this.penDown();
        this.position = x;
    }

    penDown(): void {
        this.isPenUp = false;
     }

    penUp(): void {
        this.isPenUp = true;
    }

    onChangePen(newPen: Pen) {
        this.penUp();
        this.pen = newPen;
    }    
}
```

The `move` function takes either a single position object or a pair of numeric values. This can obviously be extended as required.