# How to implement interface overload

Tags: typescript

Anders give this example of an interface overload, but I don't get how it would be implemented and used:

```
interface Fooable
{
   Foo(n:number) : string;
   Foo(s:string) : string;
}
```

Can someone give me an example of implementing and using this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Functions Overloading in interface and classes - how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219289/functions-overloading-in-interface-and-classes-how-to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Bar implements Fooable {
    Foo(n: number): string; 
    Foo(n: string): string; 
    Foo(n: any) {
        if(typeof n === 'number') {
            return n + ' is a number';
        } else if(typeof n === 'string') {
            return n + ' is a string';
        } else {
            throw new Error("Oops, null/undefined?");           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  In testing this, it seems `Foo(n: number): string;` isn't actually required in the class (it compiles without error without it.)  What is the purpose of that line?

Comment: What do you mean? I get an error removing either overload.

Comment: See below for example.

Comment: Removing two lines is different than removing one line! You can satisfy the interface by providing a function that is a subtype of the required function. In other words, a function that can take _anything_  and returns a string is an acceptable substitute for a function that can take a number or a string and return a string.

Comment: OK, great, I get it now.  But what are those lines doing?  They get compiled away - I really don't see a purpose for them as they are not actually implementing anything, yet they are in the class. (Just trying to fully understand what is going on.)

Comment: They indicate what you can call the function with. For example, you can't call bar.Foo({n: 3});

Comment: How to do it inline?