# good way to validate the number of arguments to an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

obviously arguments.length does not work.

I can change the signature to `f: (...args) => { if (args.length>0) { ..}; };`

But this removes the parameter information from the function declaration .

Any better way ?

Comment: Do you _have_ to use an arrow function? `: function() { }.bind(this)`, though less performant would have the same effect and would provide you the `arguments` object you need

Comment: yes I have to thx

Comment: What exactly do you want to validate? You never should count arguments anyway, treat `f()` the same as `f(undefined)`.

Comment: Bergi - what I wanted to write is an assert function that easily validate the number of arguments and will work also in functions defined with arrow notation

Comment: > But this removes the parameter information from the function declaration <

Sounds like you use typescript? How about [method overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688275/how-to-do-method-overloading-in-typescript)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: "no", or "maybe".

The longer answer is:  from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :

> An **arrow function** expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`). Arrow functions are always anonymous. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions and they can not be used as constructors.

The main use for arrow functions are for callbacks, to execute code as if it was executed in its parent context. Thus preventing the annoying and ugly `const that = this;` requirement and does it implicitly.

For this reason, and since it is executed anonymously, within the parent's context, there is no `arguments`, or rather the value is of the parent's context. Arrow functions solve only a general use case, not every one.

---

#### Solution 1 : legacy or "naïve" implementation

```
// const that = this;
var that = this;

...
  f: function (a, b, c) {
    ...
  }
...
```

- **Pros**
- (currently) slightly faster than arrow functions
- possess their own context (i.e. `arguments`, etc.)
- can safely be implemented in all browsers and environments
- **Cons**
- annoying `that` (or some other var name) instead of `this`.
- function cannot be external, or lose `that` reference

---

#### Solution 2 : function binding (ES5)

```
...
  f: (function (a, b, c) {
    ...
  }).bind(this)
...
```

- **Pros**
- "correct" `this` is available
- can pass any external function reference (i.e. reuse code)
- possess their own context (i.e. `arguments`, etc.)
- **Cons**
- (currently) slightly slower than arrow functions
- unexpected results if the function reference was previously bound
- no support for IE8 and perhaps other browsers *(I had to mention this, even if I cannot care less for IE8)*

---

#### Solution 3 : Destructuring assignment (ES6)

```
...
  f: (...args) => {
    const [a, b, c] = args;

    ...
  }
  g: (a, b, c, ...others) => {
    ...
  }
...
```

- **Pros**
- anonymous function
- access to parent context seemlessly
- exhibit a similar behaviour
- **Cons**
- signature tells you nothing about how it "should" be called
- may require destructuring
- (currently) slightly slower than a standard function
- not real `arguments` instance
- requires a transpiler (ex: Babel) to run in the browser, which will probably transpile into a "legacy" implementation

Comment: thx but I know all that and it does not answer my question. I guess the simple answer is 'no' ... what I wanted to write is an assert function that easily validate the number of arguments and will work also in functions defined with arrow notation

Comment: fair enough. I edited the answer to reflect my point, and added another solution that was not mentioned before.

Answer (score 3):

You've already got this figured out, spread operator + `.length` will give you the information you need if you are using arrow functions. I would consider the particular use-case you are presenting (where you need to preserve parameter information and know the length of the arguments) as more well suited to a non-arrow function:

```
 f: function(a, b, c) { console.log(arguments.length); }
```

If you are using arrow functions to preserve the parent context, you can always add `.bind(this)` to the end ([and incur a small performance penalty](http://www.2ality.com/2016/02/arrow-functions-vs-bind.html)).

I don't know exactly what you need to accomplish, but if you aren't trying to write a function with unknown arity, perhaps default arguments would allow you to handle cases where a user forgets a required parameter? ...or you could pack your arguments in an object and use `Object.keys` to determine the length:

```
let f = (args) => console.log(Object.keys(args).length);
f({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });
```

This would preserve parameter information and allow you to ascertain the length of the arguments.

Comment: I can't find the part in the "small performance penalty" link you gave that talks about the penalty. Could you please highlight it?

Comment: good info thx, but does not answer the question. I guess the simple answer is 'no' ... what I wanted to write an assert function that easily validate the number of arguments and will work also in unctions defined with arrow notation