# Spread Operator with Union Types and Tuples

Tags: typescript

I have a key that can either be of type `number` or type `[number]` or type `[number, number]`;

I created a type for each and a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) that can be either:

```
type Foo    = [number, number?];
type Bar    = number;
type FooBar = Foo | Bar;
```

I then wrote a compare method that would analyze two of these keys.

My issue is, I want to limit the compare so that the two parameters must be of the same type. IE compare of `Foo` and `Foo` or `Bar` and `Bar` but not `Foo` and `Bar`.

If I make the compare method as follows:

```
compare(key1: FooBar, key2: FooBar)
```

then it will accept this kind of miss matched compare: `compare([1], 1)`

If I define some more types as such:

```
type FooFoo = [Foo, Foo];
type BarBar = [Bar, Bar];
```

and change the compare signature to:

```
compare(keys: FooFoo|BarBar)
```

It will correctly limit the two keys to be the same type but that means that you have to pass the compare parameter as an array, which is ugly. So I decided to try and use the spread operator `...`

```
compare(...keys: FooFoo|BarBar)
```

But it returns an error saying that FooFoo needs to be an array. If I use `compare(...keys: FooFoo)` it doesn't complain (but is limited to only `FooFoo`). And if I use `compare(...keys: BarBar)` it also doesn't complain (but is limited to only `BarBar`).

Is there any way to correctly overload this method to be equivalent to:

```
//an example of what I want.
//Using Java or C#'s overloading style for illustration

function compare(k1: Bar, k2: Bar): boolean {
   return compare([key1], [key2]);
}

function compare(k1: Foo, k2: Foo): boolean {
  if (k1 === k2) { return true; }
  if (Array.isArray(k1) && Array.isArray(k2)) {
      return k1[0] === k2[0] && (k1[1] === k2[1] ||
        (!isSet(k1[1]) && !isSet(k2[1])));
  }
  return false;
}

//this would result in allowing and not allowing the following:
compare(1, 2); //valid
compare([1], [2]); //valid
compare([1, 2], [3, 4]); //valid
compare([1, 2], [3]); //valid
compare([1], [2, 3]); //valid

compare([1], 2); //not valid
compare([1, 2], 3); //not valid
compare(1, [2]); //not valid
compare(1, [2, 3]); //not valid
```

I've set up a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-spread?file=index.ts) with everything laid out. I hope what I am trying to do is possible. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You can use TypeScript overloading.

Comment: Have you tried with TypeScript 3.1?  I think this issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26676).

Comment: @SLaks I did try that. I hadn't realized I needed 3 method signatures though. So I got that part working. But ran into a new problem... When the variables being based in are set directly it works, but if they are set through a JSON parse (as they are in my use case - the data is coming from an API) it gives an error. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-spread-issue1?file=index.ts Is there any way around this without needing to check the type before calling compare?

Comment: @jcalz yes I am using version 3.1.1 and was still getting the error with the spread operator

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error in 3.1.1: `function f(...x: [string, string] | [number, number]): void {}` compiles fine in 3.1.1, but fails in 3.0 and earlier.  How sure are you that you're using 3.1.1?

Comment: @jcalz sorry my mistake, sorry. Stackblitz is running an older version so it doesnt work there. And when I moved the code over to VC which is running 3.1.1 I had copied the code incorrectly. So yes, now I have it working with the spread operator, thanks. But I'm now running into the issue I mentioned above about it complaining when I use a variable that has been parsed from JSON and not been explicitly typed. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think people are going to come to these comments looking for an answer to your followup question, so please ask it separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26676) in Typescript version 3.1 (thanks jcalz)

For a work around in older versions you can use TypeScript overloading. (thanks SLaks).
A note when using TypeScript overloading: You have to make a signature for each overload and a generic signature that will support all of the overloads together. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12689054/2502360). This initially tripped me up a bit so I thought it was worth repeating.