# TypeScript and React: How to overload a higher order component / decorator?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, higher-order-components, typescript-types

I'm building a React app using TypeScript.

I'm writing a higher order component and I would like to overload it's arguments. How can I do that?

Let me give you what I've tried so that you can understand it better:

```
const myHOC = ((value: string, anotherValue: number) | completeProps: SomeProps) => (WrappedComponent: ComponentClass) => // ... HOC code
```

So it should be either:

```
const myHOC = (value: string, anotherValue: number) => (WrappedComponent: ComponentClass) => // ...
```

or

```
const myHOC = (completeProps: SomeProps) => (WrappedComponent: ComponentClass) => // ...
```

Obviously TypeScript complains here, because it expects a `=>` to come after the brackets surrounding `value` and `anotherValue` (because it thinks that is a function). But how can I overload this HOC's parameters?

**BTW:** This HOC groups a component with another:

```
<React.Fragment>
  <WrappedComponent {this.props} />
  <ComponentInjectedByHOC valueProp={value} anotherValueProp={anotherValue} {...completeProps} />
</React.Fragment>
```

I would like to overload the parameters of the HOC, because there are a couple of values that have a high likely hood of being modified (`value` and `anotherValue`) and if not the component should just be completely customisable via the `completeProps`.

**Edit:**

This question has been marked as a possible duplicate of[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688275/is-there-a-way-to-do-method-overloading-in-typescript). But my question is different, because it is about higher order components. The marked question only deals with simple functions, not functions than return another function that return a class.

Comment: Your syntax does not make your intent clear to me, what would the overloads be ? One that takes `(value: string, anotherValue: number) => (WrappedComponent: ComponentClass) =>...` and the other  `(completeProps: SomeProps) => (WrappedComponent: ComponentClass)=>...` ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes this is correct! I added that explicitly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to do method overloading in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688275/is-there-a-way-to-do-method-overloading-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions don't have explicit overload syntax, you can use a regular function instead:

```
interface SomeProps {value: string, anotherValue: number}
function myHOC (value: string, anotherValue: number) : (WrappedComponent: ComponentClass) => JSX.Element
function myHOC (completeProps: SomeProps) : (WrappedComponent: ComponentClass) => JSX.Element
function myHOC (valueOrCompleteProps: string| SomeProps, maybeAnotherValue?: number) : (WrappedComponent: ComponentClass) => JSX.Element {
    let completeProps: SomeProps;
    if(typeof valueOrCompleteProps ==='string') {
        completeProps = { value: valueOrCompleteProps, anotherValue: maybeAnotherValue! }
    }else{
        completeProps =valueOrCompleteProps;
    }

    return (WrappedComponent: ComponentClass) => <WrappedComponent {... completeProps} />
}
```

You can also use an arrow function but you need to type it explicitly:

```
interface SomeProps {value: string, anotherValue: number}
const myHOC : {
    (value: string, anotherValue: number) : (WrappedComponent: ComponentClass) => JSX.Element
    (completeProps: SomeProps) : (WrappedComponent: ComponentClass) => JSX.Element
} = (valueOrCompleteProps: string| SomeProps, maybeAnotherValue?: number) => {
    let completeProps: SomeProps;
    if(typeof valueOrCompleteProps ==='string') {
        completeProps = { value: valueOrCompleteProps, anotherValue: maybeAnotherValue! }
    }else{
        completeProps =valueOrCompleteProps;
    }

    return (WrappedComponent: ComponentClass) => <WrappedComponent {... completeProps} />
}
```