# Check with TS that both optional params either passed or undefined

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm writing an app with React native and Typescript and I have a question.

Let's image we have a simple component with three properties, one required and two optional:

```
interface Props {
  requiredProp: string;
  optionalPropA: boolean;
  optionalPropB: Function;
}
```

In my app logic **either both optional properties have to be passed or none of them** and I'm wondering how can I check that with TS?

I can think of only two ways how I can achieve that:

1. Without using TS just simply check my condition with `if` somewhere before `return`
2. Combine two optional properties into one. Make an object with two keys (one for each property) and make a TS type that will make sure that either both or none of them exists

Some examples:

```
// Should be good because all params were passed
<SimpleComponent
  requiredProp={'Hello world'}
  optionalPropA={true}
  optionalPropB={() => {}}
/>
```

```
// Should be good because only required param was passed
<SimpleComponent
  requiredProp={'Hello world'}
/>
```

```
// Should complain that optionalPropB wasn't passed
<SimpleComponent
  requiredProp={'Hello world'}
  optionalPropA={true}
/>
```

```
// Should complain that optionalPropA wasn't passed
<SimpleComponent
  requiredProp={'Hello world'}
  optionalPropB={() => {}}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overloads for your function:

Here:

[TypeScript and React: How to overload a higher order component / decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514525/typescript-and-react-how-to-overload-a-higher-order-component-decorator)

or here: [https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/function-overloading/#:~:text=In%20TypeScript%2C%20function%20overloading%2C%20or,number%20of%20parameters%20or%20types.&text=Also%20note%20that%2C%20function%20implementation,with%20all%20the%20overloaded%20signatures](https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/function-overloading/#:%7E:text=In%20TypeScript%2C%20function%20overloading%2C%20or,number%20of%20parameters%20or%20types.&text=Also%20note%20that%2C%20function%20implementation,with%20all%20the%20overloaded%20signatures).

Your function should look something like this:

```
interface PropsInterface {
   requiredProp: string
}

interface OptionalPropsInterface extends PropsInterface {
   optionalPropA: string,
   optionalPropB: string
}

function simpleComponent(data: PropsInterface): JSX.Element
function simpleComponent(data: OptionalPropsInterface): JSX.Element
function simpleComponent(): { 
   // ...
}

export {
   simpleComponent
}
```

It will check now if one of the 2 overloads match. If not it will throw an error / underline it red

Comment: @EmilvanGalen Hello, I tried all solutions you guys adviced me and unfortunately, your didn't work for me for some reason, but the one with overloads did.

I will take a closer look on your solution and will try to make it work, pehaps I used it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use discriminated unions:

```
type Props = ({
  requiredProp: string
}) & (
  | { optionalPropA?: never, optionalPropB?: never }
  | { optionalPropA: boolean, optionalPropB?: never }
  | { optionalPropA?: never, optionalPropB: Function }
)
```

Actually I first wanted to suggest such solution:

```
type Props = {
  requiredProp: string
} & (
  | {}
  | { optionalPropA: boolean }
  | { optionalPropB: Function }
)
```

But for some reason it doesn't prevent you from using both properties at the same time, also it lets you pass basically any properties. Maybe that's because `{}` type is treated somehow differently, not sure about this, but the first snippet should work, although it's not as pretty

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way IMO to declare the Props type (alias) using both an intersection type (`&`) and a union type (`|`) like this:

```
type Props = {
  requiredProp: string;
} & (
  | never
  | {
      optionalPropA: boolean;
      optionalPropB: Function;
    }
);
```

***NOTE***: My initial solution was to use `{}` instead of `never`,
but then TypeScript does not complain when to do specify `optionalPropA` but forgot to specify `optionalPropB`