# Typescript method overloading using "async" operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-3.6

```
export class Service {

public validate() {
    return async((name: string, dob: string) => {
        //do some operation
    });
};

public validate() {
    return async((name: string, dob: string, address: string) => {
        //do some operation
    });
};
```

}

**Error: Duplicate function implementation**

**Typescript Ver: 3.8.3**

Is it possible to overload the method in the typescript? if "yes" can anyone help to resolve the above methods?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have built-in function overloading. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212625/typescript-function-overloading

Comment: Its possible but they way you are doing thats not an overload of function. check this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Comment: I couldn't able to do using async operaton

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to do method overloading in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688275/is-there-a-way-to-do-method-overloading-in-typescript)

Comment: I'm trying with "async" method but I couldn't able to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think if I suppose your two validate function return different data type such as int and string then you may do something like this.

```
function validate():string;

function validate(): number;

function validate(): any {
    return something; //Something can be string or number 
}
```

What if both return number

```
    public validate() {
    return async((name: string, dob: string, address: string) => {
        //you can do the operation and check if address is undefined
    });
};
```

Comment: The reason I want to avoid the `if check condition`

Comment: But both the methods return type is the same

Comment: So you mean to say typescript doesn't support method overloading with the same return type? as of now

Comment: Then you can have simply one method that can accept all the parameter and you can check if the parameter is being passed while calling.

Comment: "Then you can have simply one method that can accept all the parameter and you can check" This i can do ... Just i'm trying with method overloading concept

Comment: I red this blog but i coudn't able do for the async operation https://medium.com/p/c256dd63245a/responses/show

Comment: Although I never tried method overloading on typescript you can still check https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/function-overloading/ link.

Comment: Ya the above link will work but for async method, I'm facing duplicate method error

Comment: Yes https://medium.com/@kevinkreuzer/typescript-method-overloading-c256dd63245a link have good explanation as well. Ok let me check with using async .