# How do I force the following functions to be called with the correct type?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to do the following:

```
class Comm {
  _type:string
}

class EMail extends Comm {
  _type = "email"
  email: string
}

class Phone extends Comm {
  _type = "phone"
  phone:number
}

function registerCallback(_type:string, (comm:  Comm) => void){}

registerCallback("email", (e: EMail)=>{}) // Correct
registerCallback("phone", (e: EMail)=>{}) // Should be error
```

How can I make this API type safe to call the register function with correct pair of type and callback that works on the correct class ?

BTW I cannot use `_type: "email" | "phone"` , as people should be able to add their own handlers without modifying the type of the base code.

```
class Serial extends Comm {
  _type = "serial"
  ...
}
registerCallback("serial", (s: Serial)=>{})
// Should be OK without modifying any base files
```

Is this possible using parameterized objects and typing in Typescript ?

Comment: I think method overloading is what you're looking for.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688275/is-there-a-way-to-do-method-overloading-in-typescript/12689054#12689054

Comment: @SephReed I cannot verify the arguments to register() at runtime as register() gets a callback as argument, whose parameter types cannot be checked at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax errors in your code posted, perhaps it was just for the sake of example? It should look more like something like this to work properly (without any changes to the intent):

```
class Comm {
  _type: string;
}

class EMail extends Comm {
  _type = 'email';
  email: string;
}

class Phone extends Comm {
  _type = 'phone';
  phone: number;
}

function registerCallback(_type: string, fn: (comm: Comm) => void) {}

registerCallback('email', (e) => {}); // Correct
registerCallback('phone', (e) => {}); // Should be error
```

You could do this a few different ways. One easy way would be to declare an `enum` and use that to strictly enforce what values `_type` can have (declaring it as `_type: string` is not specific enough):

[image: One possible solution using enums]

Now you get an error any time you try to use an improper combination of `_type` and `fn` callback shape. However, this is fairly brittle and will break easily if you make any changes to the type definitions. It's also not very DRY and you'd have to repeat `registerCallback` definitions a lot if you want to overload it. Plus, every single time you call `registerCallback`, you'd have to pass the `_type` and `fn` as two separate arguments which seems pretty redundant.

An elegant solution here is to use Generics. You can define the types and `registerCallback` in such a way that the type is defined at *usage time* up front, but still has strict guard rails on how it can be used:

[image: A better solution using Generics]

```
class Comm {}

class EMail extends Comm {
  email: string;
}

class Phone extends Comm {
  phone: number;
}

type CommUnion = EMail | Phone;

function registerCallback<T extends CommUnion>(fn: (e: T) => void) {}

registerCallback((e: EMail) => e.email); // Correct
registerCallback((e: Phone) => e.phone); // Correct
registerCallback<EMail>((e) => e.email); // Correct
registerCallback<Phone>((e) => e.phone); // Correct
registerCallback((e: { phone: 123456789 }) => e.phone); // Correct
registerCallback((e: { email: 'me@me.com' }) => e.email); // Correct
registerCallback((e: { email: 'me@me.com' }) => e.phone); // Should be error (types don't match)
registerCallback<Phone>((e) => e.email); // Should be error (types don't match)
registerCallback((e: { foo: 'foo' }) => e.foo); // Should be error (e is improper type)
registerCallback((e) => e.email); // Should be error (no type specified)
```

See how much cleaner that looks! I highly recommend the Generic approach if you can. They can be a bit tricky though, so read up on it to learn more about how it works and get comfortable. :)

Comment: Thanks! 1) I need to know which callbacks are for email and which ones for phone. Any way to achieve that? Assume Ill be adding them to separate lists by type. 2) I would like to avoid the CommUnion type if possible. How do I specify "accept any const string type" ?

Comment: You can use TS `instanceof` operator to check the class of an object. https://javascript.info/instanceof#ref-instanceof But that might not work here, or you may need to declare a class for the callbacks themselves rather than for the value of `e`. You may need to restructure some of your code, but that's up to you, and if you have further questions on that specifically then please open a separate Question. As for ditching `CommUnion`, do you have a reason for doing so? You could swap out `CommUnion` for the base class `Comm` on line 52 but you will lose a lot of very valuable type inferences.