# Can I use function overloads in typescript with different type arrays as params

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
function handleArr(item: IUserInfo) 
function handleArr(item: IGoods | IUserInfo) {
  // do something different for IUserInfo or IGoods
}
```

I want to use funtion overloads for different params in above problems. Is there a property method for me to distinguish IGoods and IUserInfo

Comment: Given TS does not exist in runtime - you must do it yourself somehow based on unique properties of either of those types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to do method overloading in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688275/is-there-a-way-to-do-method-overloading-in-typescript)