# Implementing a function with conditional return type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let us say I want to write a function that can accept a single argument which can be either of nullable or non-nullable type. If the argument is non-nullable, then the return type should also be non-nullable. Similarly, if the argument is of nullable type, so too should be the return type.

Below is my attempt at implementing such function:

```js
type TransformKey = 'one' | 'two' | 'three'
function transform<T extends TransformKey | null>(key: T): T extends TransformKey ? string : string | null {
    if (key === null)
        return null as any
    else
        return key.toUpperCase() as any
}
```

The function signature appears to be correct, since it achieves the desired behavior on call-site, for example:

```js
const neverNullArg = 'two'
const neverNullResult: string = transform(neverNullArg)

const maybeNullArg: TransformKey | null = 'three'
const maybeNullResult: string | null = transform(maybeNullArg)
```

i.e. the return type is indeed determined by the argument type in a correct manner.

However, my issue lies with the function implementation. Without casting the return value to `any`, both return statements result in TS2322 error: `Type 'null'/'string' is not assignable to type 'T extends TransformKey ? string : string | null'`. So I was wondering how could the function be implemented in a way that satisfies the signature without defeating the typing system using `as any` casts or `// @ts-ignore`

Comment: What version of typescript?

Comment: @smac89, version 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) for your function:

```
type TransformKey = 'one' | 'two' | 'three'

function transform(key: TransformKey): string;
function transform(key: TransformKey | null): string | null;
function transform(key: any): string | null {
    if (key === null)
        return null;
    else
        return key.toUpperCase();
}
```

#### Tests

```
const neverNullArg = 'two'
const neverNullResult: string = transform(neverNullArg)

const maybeNullArg: TransformKey | null = 'three'
const maybeNullResult: string | null = transform(maybeNullArg)
```

See also: [Writing Good Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#writing-good-overloads)

Comment: Unfortunately this answer does not resolve my issue and neither does the answer in the mistakenly labeled duplicate question. The main issue is that 2nd test (`maybeNull`) does not reflect the intended type. It is equivalent to the `neverNull` test. The correct definition for `maybeNull` would be `'three' as TransformKey | null`. Calling `transform` with such argument would result in TS2345 error. And the 3rd test with `alwaysNull` is not pertinent to my issue.

Comment: @arslancharyev31 Updated my answer. Does that work for you now?

Comment: That's brilliant, works perfectly, thanks. Typing the implementation argument with `any` and narrowing down that type in overloaded declarations is an interesting approach that I never thought of before.

Comment: @arslancharyev31 Lol I saw it being done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688275/is-there-a-way-to-do-method-overloading-in-typescript), so I just adopted their answer. Maybe that answer should be the one marked as duplicate. Also this is the way it is done in the link I have in my answer, so I guess this is really the typescript way of doing overloads

Comment: Your answer combines the 2 concepts together to make a new, unique answer. None of those questions are duplicates of mine. I probably didn't formulate the question in accordance with specifics of my issue.